# Properly binding maven exec plugin to test phase

Tags: maven, testing, gruntjs, mocha.js

In a Maven project I use maven-exec-plugin to launch my Grunt tests. It goes like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>cmd</executable>
          <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>/C</argument>
            <argument>grunt --no-color test</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>  
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

With that I can run `mvn test` and my grunt `test` task will be executed: if the tests pass, the maven build pass and if the tests fail the maven build fail. When some tests fail I have the following output:

```
  .............................................  1 failing
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 3.496s
  [INFO] Finished at: ** ** ** **:**:** CEST ****
  [INFO] Final Memory: *M/*M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default) on project *****: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6) -> [Help 1]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have the 'usual' maven output for failing tests. Something like: `Build failure, there are failing tests`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. The build failure message shows the exception thrown by the failing plugin; in `exec-maven-plugin`'s case, that will only ever be the report of the exit code. It won't consider anything else in the command's behaviour.

If you were determined, you could rewrite or extend `exec-maven-plugin`, or perhaps write something similar in Groovy to throw an exception with a more specific message.

(A [grunt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin) exists, but it also delegates to `exec-maven-plugin`.)

Comment: Yup that's what I feared. Thanks for the pointer to `grunt-maven-plugin` though I prefer using `exec-maven-plugin`.